# Javascript Run function on all input fields on focus

Tags: javascript

I want to execute a function when any of the text field is focused.

Something like this, BUT purely in Javascript - NOT IN JQUERY

```
$("input").focus(function() {
    alert("Hello World");
});
```

I am trying:

```
document.getElementById("text1").onfocus = alert(1);
```

But this only shows the alert after loading page, nothing else.

Thanks

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` - return all element by selector, in loop you can: assign function reference for handler, or use addEventListener

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementsByTagName('input');` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like some aspects of jQuery, but do not want to include the entire library in your project, you can check out [*You Might Not Need jQuery*](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#on). You can set the minimum version of IE that you support, in the settings at the top of the page.

```js
function addEventListener(el, eventName, handler) {
  if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener(eventName, handler);
  } else {
    el.attachEvent('on' + eventName, function(){
      handler.call(el);
    });
  }
}

function addEventListeners(selector, type, handler) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    addEventListener(elements[i], type, handler);
  }
}

addEventListeners('input', 'focus', function(e) {
  if (this.value !== this.placeholder) {
    this.value = this.placeholder;
  } else {
    this.value = '';
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="One" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Two" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Three" />
```

Comment: Oh Thank You , this is the perfect thing  I am looking for 

Plus great thanks for the link, If I could upvote you, I would have done

Comment: Just want to ask , http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#on also have Firefox and Chrome specific guidelines?

Comment: @Jack, IE is usually the ***special case***. What works in Firefox *should* work in Chrome and vice-versa. If you need clarification, take a look at [MDN: EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for information on browser compatibility/support (at the bottom of the page).

Answer (score 3):

Get elements by tag name & loop("Iterate") on them for attaching focus.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbytagname.asp

```
var x=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

**EDIT :** Put this at the end of page

```
<script>
  var x=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
x[i].addEventListener('focus',function(){
       alert("focus");
    });
}

</script>
```

Comment: To loop on something is also called iterating.

Comment: @Jack, you should call this script after DOM loaded, for example put it in end _body_ tag, or call on _load_ event.

Comment: i run x.onfocus = alert(1); but it only alert on page load but not on onfocus

Comment: @Jack, because you should assign _reference_ to function, but you assign function result, change to `x.onfocus = function(){alert(1);}` and all work

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way with [*document.querySelectorAll*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for new browser

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
```

and then in loop for example use [*addEventListener*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```
for(var i=0,len=inputs.length;i<len;i++){
    inputs[i].addEventListener('focus',function(){
        //handle event
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This one supports input elements that are loaded asynchronously too.

```js
document.addEventListener("focusin", inputBoxListener)

function inputBoxListener(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === "INPUT") {
    console.log("focused on input")
  }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusin_event

Answer (score 0):

I know I am probably late to this, but I just wanted to add my 2 cents, as I see a lot of Stackoverflow answers like this still using JQuery and many people have moved on from JQuery, and might want another option

You could either use the focusin event or capture the focus in the Capturing phase from the top down, in either JQuery or JS, If It works in JS, it should work in the other, as I dont use JQ

```
let form = document.forms.myForm;
form.addEventListener('focus', (event) => {
    console.log('Focused!');
    console.log(event.target);
}, true);

//Work around focusin
form.addEventListener('focusin', (event) => {
    console.log('Focused In!');
    console.log(event.target);
});
```